# Nodemon server not reloading in MacOS / OS X

Tags: node.js, macos, nodemon

I am using;

```
npm: 6.14.8
node: 14.15.1
nodemon: 2.0.6
```

I have just upgraded to use MacOS Big Sur and I notice that `nodemon` no longer seems to correctly watch file changes on a Node project and restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and research, it now works if I use this;

```
nodemon index.js -L
```

Hope this helps anyone with the problem. I am not yet aware of why the legacy flag is needed now, but I have raised the issue with the developers.